# At what stage does file upload actually happen in a Tomcat + spring web-application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, file-upload

This might be an implementation dependent question. My web application runs on tomcat and I use spring framework. Suppose I have the following in one of the controllers that handles URLs-

```
@Controller
public class IncomingDataHandlerV1 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v1/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Object uploadFile(@RequestParam("logFile") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
        Model model) throws IOException {

    }
}
```

As we see here, the method uploadFile expects a file upload, which is the first parameter. My question is, would the tomcat container already have received the file from the client (browser) in its entirety already when control comes to this method? Or is the upload happening only when I start to read off the file input stream?

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that the file is uploaded to a temporary fie, then your servlet code is called with the appropriate variable set to the file bytes.

For instance, you can specify the standard Apache multi-part uploader, and tell the J2EE container the max file size. But by default a huge file will throw a 500 exception. I usually overload the standard uploader with a class that puts exceptions into the session, meaning the servlet code can analyse the cause and report the error intelligently.

I am using portlet technology and earlier versions of Spring - I hope I am not too far off topic.